# How can I run pytest in another folders in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

In folder `[Root]/src/app`, I have a file `services_factory.py`, for example:

```
class Describing:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_description(self):
    pass

class APIService(Describing):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_description(self):
    return 'Here provide services for APIs'

class DatabaseService(Describing):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_description(self):
    return 'Here provide services for Database'

class Injector:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def get_service(self, type='API'):
    services = {
      "API": APIService,
      "DB": DatabaseService
    }
    return services[type]()
```

At the end of file `services_factory.py`, I add an unittest, ex:

```
def test_services_injector():
  injector = Injector()
  api_service = injector.get_service('API')
  db_service = injector.get_service('DB')
  assert api_service.get_description() == 'Here provide services for APIs'
  assert db_service.get_description() == 'Here provide services for Database'
```

Then, cmd: `$ pytest src/app/services_injector.py`, it worked nicely.

---

But when I create a file `test_services_factory.py` in `[Root]/tests/app`, for example:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


def test_services_injector():
  assert 'a' == 'a'
```

I can't import the classes in my `services_factory.py`.

**So, how can I quickly fix this problem?**

Comment: use pytest like this `python -m pytest`

Comment: Could you please include syntax you are using for importing that class in your description ?

Comment: @MjZac Work like a charm! You've just saved my day!

Comment: @ChandaKorat : `$ python -m pytest` work fine. Here is what I did for importing: `from src.app.services_injector import Injector, APIService, DatabaseService` . If having any another solution, could you please let me know? Thanks so much for your attention.

Comment: Try by adding an empty \__init__.py  file to your test directory and each of its sub directories i.e add one python file named as \__init__.py to your folder src and to folder app.

Comment: @ChandaKorat I've just tried, then it work perfectly with command `$ pytest tests/app/test_services_factory.py` - without prefix - `python -m`. Last but not least, your solution seem to be right ever. Thanks for you help.